# Replacing same type of value for different keys in json

Tags: java, json, java-8

I have a code to replace one key value at a time of a json and give output.
The problem comes when we have same type of value for different keys in json body.
I want to replace only one key value at a time even if values are same for different keys and give json output.

Here is my code.

```
    package test;

import java.util.*;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

public class TestClass {

    public static Map<String,Object> params = new HashMap<String,Object>();
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {
            String json = "{\"csp-report\":{\"blocked-uri\":\"inline\",\"column-number\":8016,\"document-uri\":\"referrer\",\"column\":8016}}";
            JSONObject inputJson = new JSONObject(json);
            List<String> lst = new ArrayList<String>();
            lst = findKeysOfJsonObject(inputJson, lst);
            System.out.println("------------------------------------------");
            Iterator hmIterator = params.entrySet().iterator();
            while (hmIterator.hasNext()) {
                Map.Entry mapElement = (Map.Entry)hmIterator.next();
                //System.out.println(mapElement.getKey() + " : " + mapElement.getValue());
                //inputJson.remove(mapElement.getKey().toString());
                //inputJson.put(mapElement.getKey().toString(),mapElement.getValue());
                System.out.println(json.replace(mapElement.getValue().toString(),"superman"));
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private static List<String> findKeysOfJsonArray(JSONArray jsonIn, List<String> keys) throws JSONException {
        List<String> keysFromArr = new ArrayList<>();

        if (jsonIn != null && jsonIn.length() != 0) {
            for (int i = 0; i < jsonIn.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject jsonObjIn = jsonIn.getJSONObject(i);
                keysFromArr = findKeysOfJsonObject(jsonObjIn, keys);
            }
        }

        return keysFromArr;
    }

    private static List<String> findKeysOfJsonObject(JSONObject jsonIn, List<String> keys) throws JSONException {

        Iterator<String> itr = jsonIn.keys();
        List<String> keysFromObj = makeList(itr);
        keys.addAll(keysFromObj);

        itr = jsonIn.keys();
        while (itr.hasNext()) {
            String itrStr = itr.next();
            JSONObject jsout = null;
            JSONArray jsArr = null;
            if (jsonIn.get(itrStr).getClass() == JSONObject.class) {
                jsout = jsonIn.getJSONObject(itrStr);
                findKeysOfJsonObject(jsout, keys);
            } else if (jsonIn.get(itrStr).getClass() == JSONArray.class) {
                jsArr = jsonIn.getJSONArray(itrStr);
                keys.addAll(findKeysOfJsonArray(jsArr, keys));
            } else if (jsonIn.get(itrStr).getClass() == String.class) {
                System.out.println(itrStr+ "-" + jsonIn.get(itrStr));
                params.put(itrStr,jsonIn.get(itrStr));
            }else if (jsonIn.get(itrStr).getClass() == Integer.class){
                params.put(itrStr,jsonIn.get(itrStr));
            }
        }
        return keys;
    }

    public static List<String> makeList(Iterator<String> iter) {
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        while (iter.hasNext()) {
            list.add(iter.next());
        }
        return list;
    }
}
```

what am i missing here.
[image: Expected vs Actual Output]

Answer (score 0):

### Solution

Replace -

```
 while (hmIterator.hasNext()) {
     Map.Entry mapElement = (Map.Entry)hmIterator.next();
     //System.out.println(mapElement.getKey() + " : " + mapElement.getValue());
     // inputJson.remove(mapElement.getKey().toString());
     // inputJson.put(mapElement.getKey().toString(),mapElement.getValue());
     System.out.println(json.replace(mapElement.getValue().toString(),"superman"));
 }
```

with -

```
while (hmIterator.hasNext()) {
    Map.Entry mapElement = (Map.Entry) hmIterator.next();
    String keyToBeSearchedFor = "\"" + mapElement.getKey().toString() + "\"";
    StringBuffer buf = new StringBuffer(json);

    // add 3 to start because of 2 double-quotes surrounding the key + 1 colon character after the double-quote after the key.
    int start = json.indexOf(keyToBeSearchedFor) + mapElement.getKey().toString().length() + 3;
    int end = start + mapElement.getValue().toString().length();
    if (mapElement.getValue() instanceof String) {
        // if the value is a String, we have to take the surrounding double quotes of the value into account.
        end += 2;
        stringToBeReplaced = "\"superman\"";
    }
    //System.out.println("Substring about to be replaced with superman=" + json.substring(start, end));
    buf.replace(start, end, stringToBeReplaced);
    System.out.println(buf);
    stringToBeReplaced = "superman"; // revert back to default value for subsequent iterations.
}
```

Output with new code snippet -

```
document-uri-referrer
blocked-uri-inline
------------------------------------------
{"csp-report":{"blocked-uri":"inline","column-number":superman,"document-uri":"referrer","column":8016}}
{"csp-report":{"blocked-uri":"inline","column-number":8016,"document-uri":"superman","column":8016}}
{"csp-report":{"blocked-uri":"inline","column-number":8016,"document-uri":"referrer","column":superman}}
{"csp-report":{"blocked-uri":"superman","column-number":8016,"document-uri":"referrer","column":8016}}
```

### Explanation

In the original code snippet, [`.replace()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace(char,%20char)) is used which replaces *all* occurrences of a substring with a new string. As a result -

```
json.replace("8016","superman")
```

replaces all occurrences of `8016` with `superman`, which is not the desired behaviour. The OP has mentioned that in each iteration, only 1 occurrence of the value should be replaced with `superman`.

To find the index of the substring which needs to be replaced, we can make use of the fact that the substring to be replaced will occur immediately after the key (with the 2 surrounding double-quotes) in the current iteration.

### Word of Caution

This solution may not work if there are multiple keys in the `JSON` having the same name in different depths inside the `JSON`.
For example -

```
String json = "{\"csp-report\":{\"blocked-uri\":\"inline\",\"column-number\":8016,\"document-uri\":\"referrer\",\"column\":8016,\"node\":{\"column\":8016}}}";
```

Comment: Hi @Dhruv , I am getting first  output as {"csp-report":{"blocked-uri":"inline","column-number":,"document-uri":"referrer","column":8016}} , not working as expected

Comment: Hi @smith, what is the `json` `String` you are using as input ?